# IIS hosted app triggers run time error when url contains a "-"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, redirect, iis, godaddy-api

I have an VS2017 AspNet MVC 5 app hosted on a 2016 Server and IIS. Each client has its own website with its own copy of the web app. Using godaddy.com I forward (with keep mask checked) the client domain to the sub-domain in the IIS and everything has been working fine for years. The client can access the web app and see its domain name in the browser url.
Example: myclientdomain.com forward with mask to myclientdomain.mycompanydomain.com but shows in the browser as myclientdomain.com

Now, I have this new client whose domain is newclient-domain.com (It has a dash) and it was forwarded exactly like the others, however, after the page loads, if the user clicks the only button in the page,  it triggers a runtime error saying:
"The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.]"

Since all the others don't have this error, I am inclined to think it is the dash in the domain name. Am I right? Is there any solution other than removing the dash from the domain name?

Comment: I would check if client site is using ssl and certificate has valid certification chain.

Comment: https://benohead.com/blog/2014/01/14/asp-net-mvc-the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-__requestverificationtoken-is-not-present/